# How to adjust page to scroll to center on clicking on carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get it so that when you click on the carousel, the page will adjust to have the carousel in the center. This website (http://studionewwork.com/) shows this when you click on their carousel. I'm still learning about Jquery so I'm not yet adept at commands yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/614/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true,
        pagination: true,
        lazyLoad: true
    });
});


$('.owl-demo').on('click', function(e) { 
  var el = $( e.target.getAttribute('href') );
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  var elHeight = el.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset;

  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
  }
  else {
    offset = elOffset;
  }
  var speed = 700;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:offset}, speed);
});
```

Comment: sry is not clear for me http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Comment: @Osgux I'm trying to get each carousel to adjust to the middle of the viewport when you click/interact with it, just like that sample website I posted has...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I updated your fiddle to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/649/

Basically you are using `$(".owl-demo")` as if it's a class, but it's an ID. Then the onClick function tries to get the clicked element but fails doing so.

`var el = $( e.target.getAttribute('href') );`

This line basically says:

Get the href-attribute from the clicked element and use jQuery to locate any elements matching the `href` attribute. I removed this since you don't specify the href attribute anywhere.

```
$('.owl-carousel').on('click', function(e) { 

  var el = $(".lazyOwl", this);
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  var elHeight = el.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset;

  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
  }
  else {
    offset = elOffset;
  }
  var speed = 700;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:offset}, speed);
});
```

Please note that the example carousel you posted doesn't work as expected on my Macbook Air 11''. The carousel jumps around whenever I click on it.

Comment: When clicking the prev and next button, it causes the carousel to jump high. http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/650/ I tried adding it to the class selector but it didn't work.

Comment: Use the javascript in my stack overflow answer. It only scrolls when you click the carousel items

Comment: I'd like it to also do the same when you press the prev or next button though.

Comment: Then change the first line '.owl-carousel img'  to just '.owl-carousel'.  That will do the trick :)

Comment: I don't think I was clear. :p I mean't that, right now, if you press next or prev, you'll see the carousel adjust not to the middle but move slightly more up than the middle. http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/651/  How can I get it so that when you press prev or next, it will still adjust to the middle, just as clicking the actual carousel does? :)

Comment: Ah I see sorry. Yeah,  i will fix this in a few minutes :) sorry

Comment: Thank you! This helped so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101548/discussion-between-user2252219-and-praszyk).